# How to query in sql from three table in one statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables as shown below.

How to get (in one query statement)  the "product _name"  that has been ordered by the user_id =1 ? (product_name for 1 ,2,3 that user_1 ordered) ?

[image]

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server? MS Access? This will impact the structure of the SQL code.

Comment: Is your products table really called `Pruducts`? Note that you may need to alter this in any SQL code provided.

Comment: Product is the table name , i am using DB Browser for SQLite for practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand your question...

Maybe this could help you

```
SELECT product_name
FROM orders
INNER JOIN products ON products.product_id = orders.product_id
WHERE orders.user_id = 1
```

Note that 
- the users table is not required in this case since you don't care about the user name
- you will get duplicate lines for the same product_name

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would help

```
select * from products
where exists (
   select 1 from orders o
   inner join users u
      on o.user_id = u.user_id
   where o.product_id = u.product_id
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the 3 tables:

```
select u.user_name, p.*
from products p inner join orders o
on o.product_id = p.product_id
inner join users u
on u.user_id = o.user_id
where u.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just needed a `(inner)join` between two tables orders and products

```
select p.product_name 
  from products p
  join orders o on p.product_id = o.product_id
 where o.user_id = 1
```

or `natural join` might be used

```
select product_name 
  from products p
  natural join orders o
 where user_id = 1
```